# Comparing values of a list in python with a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I got two **lists**

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now I want to know when one element of list **a** is the same as an element of list **b**. I want to execute more code based on that exact moment

I am Sorry that my question might have been a bit unclear. But that was the result I wanted to have :)

```
a = ["82.198.205.119","82.198.205.119","82.198.205.119","82.198.205.119", "82.198.205.118", "82.198.205.118", "82.198.205.118"]
b = ["82.198.205.119", "82.198.205.118"]

for idx_y, y in enumerate(b):
  for idx_x, x in enumerate(a):
    if a[idx_x] == b[idx_y]:
      print "found a match " + str(a[idx_x])
print("The for loop ended")
```

*I am sorry for this question guys :) I was a big noob back in that time and couldn't figure out that one on myself.*

Comment: do you mean you want to see what elements are in both lists and then do something with that element in b?

Comment: Could you add some code so we can comment on your implementation?

Comment: please post the expected output....

Comment: You should try providing a title to your question that more accurately reflects *what* you want to do.  Not how you think it needs to be done.  Whatever you're asking it might not need to involve a for loop at all! :)

Comment: This answer could be as simple as `[aa for aa in a if aa in b]` or incredibly complex. As the other commenters have requested -- please post your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for x in a:
    for y in b:
        if a[x] == b[y]:
            #Do stuff here
            print "found a match " + str(a[x])
        elif y == len(b) - 1:
            break
```